# What's wrong with my code implementing RSA?

Tags: java, encryption, rsa

I've only been learning about cryptography for the last 3 weeks and coding in Java for about a year. I'm working on a practice project that is supposed to generate public and private key pairs, encrypt plaintext using public key, and decrypt ciphertext using private key. I don't get any compilation errors when I try to run it, but I'm not getting any output either.

I'm thinking that I'm not using the right variables or call methods where they belong, but the more I try to make heads and tails of what's going on, the more confused I become. Can anyone take a look and point out the issue(s)?

Sorry for the janky mess. Note: The comments are all instruction that I've been given.

```
package project4;


import java.math.BigInteger; // for generating prime numbers and for large integer arithematics
import java.util.Base64;     // for encoding of byte array to string and decode string to byte array
import java.util.Random;     // need this class when generating random prime numbers

/*
 * This class implements the RSA algorithm for public-key cryptography using BigInteger class.
 */
public class PKC {
    // modulus = p * q
    // private_key = public_key^-1 mod (p-1)*(q-1)
    BigInteger p, q, public_key, private_key, modulus;
    Random rnd= new Random();   
    
    


    // initialize p and q with two prime numbers of 1024 bits long using BigInteger's constructor
    // the likelihood that p or q is not a prime number is <= 2^-10
    // 
    // also initialize modulus as p * q
    PKC() { 
        
        p = BigInteger.probablePrime(1024, rnd);
        q = p.nextProbablePrime();
        modulus = p.multiply(q); 
        
    }
    

    // initialize the public and private key pair
    // the public key is a 20 bit long prime number (probability of not prime is <= 2^-10
    // private key is the multiplicative inverse of the public key modulo (p-1)*(q-1) --- public BigInteger modInverse(BigInteger modulus)
    void genKeyPair() {
        public_key = BigInteger.probablePrime(20, rnd);
        private_key = public_key.modInverse(modulus);   
        
    }
    
    
    // encrypt a plaintext message as a string using the public key 
    // return the ciphertext as a string (using Base64 encoding)
    
    //string --> bytearray --> biginteger --> bytearray --> encode --> string
    String encrypt(String m) {
        
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(m.getBytes());

    }
    
    // decrypt a ciphertext using the private key 
    // return the plaintext as string
    //string --> decode --> bytearray --> biginteger --> decrypt --> biginteger --> bytearray --> string
    String decrypt(String c) {
        
        return new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(c));
        
    }
    
    // encrypt a plaintext message as a BigInteger using the public key
    BigInteger encrypt(BigInteger m) {
        
        return m.modPow(public_key, modulus);
        
    }
    
    // decrypt a ciphertext message as a BigInteger using the private key
    BigInteger decrypt(BigInteger c) {
        
        return c.modInverse(modulus);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        PKC pkc = new PKC(); 
        pkc.genKeyPair();
        System.out.printf("p: %d\n\nq: %d\n\npublic key: %d\n\nprivate key: %d\n\nmodulus: %d\n\n", 
                pkc.p, pkc.q, pkc.public_key, pkc.private_key, pkc.modulus); 
        
        BigInteger m = new BigInteger("438709437431787");
        BigInteger c = pkc.encrypt(m);
        
        System.out.printf("plaintext: %d\n\nciphertext: %d\n\ndecrypted text: %d\n\n", m, c, pkc.decrypt(c));
        
        String plaintext = "test message";
        String ciphertext = pkc.encrypt(plaintext);
        
        System.out.printf("plaintext: %s\n\nciphertext: %s\n\ndecrypted text: %s\n\n", plaintext, ciphertext, pkc.decrypt(ciphertext));
    }
}
```

Comment: Programming questions that aren't about the cryptographic aspects of code are off-topic here. Since this is about the non-cryptographic parts of the code (no output), it's off-topic. 

There are, however, some severe cryptographic issues with this code. Most obviously, Java's BigInteger class isn't suitable for cryptographic use, and its util.Random is utterly insecure. Also you're doing "textbook" RSA which is insecure since it's missing the essential padding. You need to be using the JCA classes, which will implement RSA securely.

Comment: You don't use any public key to "encrypt", and any private key to decrypt. How is it suppose to work?

Comment: The earlier comment by @SAIPeregrinus is about the question being on the cryptography site, from which it was migrated.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some of the obvious problems:

> ```
> PKC() {      
>    p = BigInteger.probablePrime(1024, rnd);
>    q = p.nextProbablePrime();
> ```

The two prime factors quite near to each other; this makes `pq` quite easy to factor.  This doesn't affect the correctness; it does affect the security.

> ```
> void genKeyPair() {
>    public_key = BigInteger.probablePrime(20, rnd);
> ```

This does not take any precautions to ensure that the generated public exponent is relatively prime to `(p-1)(q-1)`, which is necessary for the next step to succeed (well, if you did the next step correctly

> ```
> // private key is the multiplicative inverse of the public key modulo (p-1)*(q-1) --- public BigInteger modInverse(BigInteger modulus)
>
>  void genKeyPair() {
>    ...
>    private_key = public_key.modInverse(modulus);
> ```

This code does not correspond to the comment; the generated private key is incorrect

> ```
> BigInteger decrypt(BigInteger c) {     
>     return c.modInverse(modulus);
> }
> ```

This is not the correct decryption procedure.

Comment: Thanks so much for the feedback. I knew there were likely multiple things wrong, but your explanations helped my understanding.